# HTTP Post request for flutter gives me : Exception has occurred. ClientException (Invalid response line)

Tags: python, flutter, api, http, post

I'm trying to send a post request using API built with python. This is for a mobile app in flutter. however I keep getting an error message of : Exception has occurred. ClientException (Invalid response line).

```
 Future<http.Response> testPost(workout_type, bodypart, workout_freq, 
 weights_pref, email) async {

  final uri = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5554/api/save-workkout');
  final headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {
     "workout_type": workout_type,
     "bodypart": bodypart,
     "workout_freq": workout_freq,
     };
  String jsonBody = json.encode(body);
  print(body);
  final resp = await http.post(
    uri,
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonBody
  );
  print(resp.body);
  return resp;


Data to be sent :
var workout_type = 1;
var bodypart = [1, 20];
var workout_freq = 2;
```

Comment: Is the error from your code, or from the remote server?

Comment: I'm guessing code, because it works fine in postman

Comment: Guess?  Surely you know whether the error is from your code or not??

Comment: it is the remote server then, i dont see any issues with the code

Answer (score 0):

```
 var map = Map<String, String>();
     map[workout_type]= workout_type,
     map[bodypart]= bodypart,
     map[workout_freq]=workout_freq,


          final uri =
              Uri.parse('http://');
         
          Map<String, String> headers = {
            //your headers
          };
          var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
            ..fields.addAll(map);
          request.headers.addAll(headers);
          var response = await request.send();
    
            final respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();
            final responseJson = json.decode(respStr);
            print(responseJson);
```

try this it will work i think so.